# 400 Resource name should start with "/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/"

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-scheduler

When using the Python client API for the Google Cloud Scheduler I always get the above error message for some reason. I also tried to start the parent path without the slash but got the same result.
Any hint is much appreciated!

```
import os
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

def gcloudscheduler(data, context):
    current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    abs_auth_path = os.path.join(current_folder, 'auth.json')
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = abs_auth_path


    response = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient().create_job(data["parent"], data["job"])
    print(response)
```

I used following parameter:

```
{"job": {
        "pubsub_target": {
            "topic_name": "trade-tests",
            "attributes": {
                "attrKey": "attrValue"
            }
        },
        "schedule": "* * * * *"
    },
 "parent": "/projects/my-project-id/locations/europe-west1"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was actually not the `parent` parameter but the incorrect format of the `topic-name`. It should have been `projects/my-project-id/topics/trade-tests`. Even though the error message says it should with a slash. But it is in line with the API doc [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Scheduler.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Scheduler.V1.PubsubTarget.html#Google_Cloud_Scheduler_V1_PubsubTarget_TopicName) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.scheduler.v1#google.cloud.scheduler.v1.PubsubTarget).

The problem was just that the error message didn't say which resource name the error was about.